# Angular TypeScript service this is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Here is my Angular TypeScript **Interceptor**:

```
export module httpMock_interceptor {
  export class Interceptor  {
      static $inject: string[] = ['$q'];
      constructor(public $q: ng.IQService) {}
       public request(config: any) {
         console.log(this);
       }
     }
   }
```

Here is my **module** where I am registering as service.

```
   import {httpMock_interceptor as interceptor} from './httpMock.interceptor';
   var httpMock: ng.IModule = angular.module("httpMockTs", []);
   httpMock.service("httpMockInterceptor",interceptor.Interceptor);
   httpMock.config.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
   httpMock.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider:  ng.IHttpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.unshift('httpMockInterceptor');
}]);
```

When the app starts running, the interceptor constructor initializing the **$q service**, but when it goes to the method  **request** where I am use **this** keyword, browser says **this** is undefined. Can anyone tell me where I am doing the mistake.

And Here is my transpiled code for **interceptor**

```
export var httpMock_interceptor;
 (function (httpMock_interceptor) {
   class Interceptor {
    constructor(_q) {
        this._q = _q;
    }
    request(config) {
        console.log(this);
    }
   }
Interceptor.$inject = ['$q'];
httpMock_interceptor.Interceptor = Interceptor;
})(httpMock_interceptor || (httpMock_interceptor = {}));
```

**Module**

```
import { httpMock_interceptor as interceptor } from './httpMock.interceptor';
var httpMock = angular.module("httpMockTs", []);
httpMock.service("httpMockInterceptor", interceptor.Interceptor);
httpMock.config.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
httpMock.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.unshift('httpMockInterceptor');
}]);
export { httpMock };
```

Comment: maybe it helps when you show us the transpiled JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

try using an arrow function that maintains a reference as "this" to the container object or rather interceptor:

```js
public request = (config: any) => {
  console.log(this);
}
```

For background see: Lambdas and using 'this' @ http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors), the interceptor should be a function that returns an object literal with properties like `request`, so I would guess the `request` function is called directly without any `this` object.